# Beautiful Color Schemes for 3D Plots

Tags: plotting

I need to plot a number of 3D graphs for my project and I want the plots to appear beautiful. I have used the following color functions for my plots but none of them seem to impress me: CMYKcolors, Sunsetcolors, Rainbow etc. I think there are other ways to make a plot by combining different colors but I am not aware how to do it.

P.s. I know it seems like an unimportant question but I don't know much about mathematica and want my work to be presentable :)

Comment: You can use `Blend` to create your own color function. BTW, just to confirm, have you already checked the [`guide/ColorSchemes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ColorSchemes.html) page in document center?

Comment: Yes I have checked these schemes and plotted my graphs with some of them but they don't seem so presentable.

Comment: I will try Blend and then see what result I get:)

Comment: "beautiful" is subjective (your "beautiful" can just as well be my "boring"); you might want to present examples of what you think is beautiful so there's something concrete to work with.

Comment: https://github.com/wanglongqi/ColorBrewer . Make use of color palette from http://colorbrewer2.org in Mathematica

Comment: Questions that are primarily opinion-based are [off-topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) here.

Comment: https://colorhunt.co/

Answer (score 5):

- We can use `Format->Stylesheet->Book->Textbook` to select the theme.

[image]

- And use `Alt`+8 to input the code.

```
ContourPlot3D[ Cos[x]Sin[y]+Cos[y]Sin[z]+Cos[z]Sin[x]==0,{x,-2π,2π}, {y,-2π,2π},{z,-2π,2π},Mesh->None,Boxed->False]
```

[image]

- Compare with the default scheme and  the Textbook scheme.

[image]

Comment: ? I guess you post the answer in wrong place?

Comment: @xzczd  I think the default 3D scheme is not beatuful then the Textbook scheme.